# What is the correct Firestore security Rule for the following scenario?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore db like this

- users

  - {userId}

    - boards

      - {boardId}

        - Board Data

I have firestore security rules setup like this.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId ;
    }
  }
}
```

How should I setup the rules that-

- Users can only access their own data.
- No one can access the root users collection

Comment: What's the problem with your current rules?

Comment: Someone said they could access all the users in the root users collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [overlapping match statement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements) in your rules, since you use `match /{document=**}` which maps to **ALL** documents in your database (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#open_access)).

So, since:

1. In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the access is allowed if **any of the conditions is true**, and
2. For the `match /{document=**}` statement your rule is `allow read: if request.auth != null;`, then

every authenticated user can read any `user` document (you don't restrict on the `uid` as you do for the `users` collection. And actually you cannot do so, since `match /{document=**}` does not specifically target the `users` collection).

The best is to remove this block and just keep the following block.

```
match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
  allow read, create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId ;
}
```

And if you need to grant read access to other collections, use a rule for each collection, instead of using the wildcard approach.

---

PS: You may double check if you really need to do `match /users/{userId}/{document=**}`, which grants access to all subcollections of the `users` docs. You may just need to do `match /users/{userId}`.